# Logic analyzer interference when analyzing SPI bus

Tags: spi, logic-analyzer

I'm trying to analyze SPI EEPROM with a logic analyzer.
The logic analyzer is connected to the spi eeprom via ~20cm wires + SOIC8 Testing Clip (Only MOSI/MISO/CS/SCLK/GND are connected to the logic analyzer)
The circuit board that the SPI EEPROM soldered on works fine when not connected to the logic analyzer, however when the logic analyzer is connected the SPI EEPROM gets halted / stuck (prevents the PC from booting), which prevents me from analyzing the bus.

What might be the reason for that?

[SPI Flash Datasheet](http://www.elm-tech.com/ja/products/spi-flash-memory/gd25q64/gd25q64.pdf) (Its actually Gigadevice 25B64CSIG, but thats the closest datasheet I could find)

[Logic Analyzer](https://reference.digilentinc.com/reference/instrumentation/digital-discovery/start)

Configuration:

[image]
[image]

Thanks.

Comment: Why did you not connect the ground?

Comment: I did connect GND, forgot to mention it. edited the question, Thanks.

Comment: What speed are you running the SPI bus at? Does it work if you reduce the speed?

Comment: @WoltCage - Hi, (a) Can you edit the question to add a link to the manufacturer's webpage or datasheet for your specific logic analyser? (b) Do you have an oscilloscope to view the SPI bus signals with & without your logic analyser attached, to see what differences there are? If so, please add relevant "working" & "non-working" scope traces into the question. If you have problems doing that, then add image links into a comment and one of us will insert them into the question. (c) What is the SPI EEPROM part number & its Vdd voltage? (d) What is the overall device e.g. STB, PC etc? Thanks.

Comment: I've updated the question